# How to chose the correct analysis to use

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have 2 datasets in R called `good` and `bad`. We have looked at 4000 players on `good` and 4000 players in `bad`. 
The dataset `good` contains
`game_id` = 1, 2, ... 20 and `percent_played` = 1.2, 14.8, ... 3.4.

Similar for `bad`.

Here `game_id` tells us which game has been played and `percent_played` tells us the percent the game has been played - so if it has a high value, say 20%, it is a very popular game and if it's value is low, say 1%, it is not a popular game. (The sum of all integers in percent_played equals 100.)

We want to investigate the difference between the 2 group `good` and `bad` and see if there is a difference in the games that have been played in the two groups.

I was thinking of using Factor Analysis or Principal Component Analysis since I want to find the most popular games in `good` and `bad` and compare these but I'm not sure if it's the best thing to do.

What would be the best way to make an analysis of this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two datasets, each with data on 20 games. For each game, each dataset tells you what percentage of the 4,000 players played the game.

I would start by just looking at a contingency table: you should be able to see right away if (say) game 1 was really popular with the "good" gamers, but not the "bad" gamers. If you convert the percentages to raw numbers, you can use a chi-square test to determine whether the differences are statistically significant (although with such a large sample size and a 20x2 table, it would be a small miracle if you didn't find a significant difference).

More informative than the test statistic itself would be the actual vs. expected cell counts: if (say) game 1 has a much different expected count than what you actually see, that is good evidence that game 1 is contributing to the significant result.